# Multiple interceptors at different levels/(sub)modules. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have 2+ interceptors in app that I am helping to write: 1 in module that is generic and each subapp (that is represented with its own submodule) has its 'local' interceptor with code specific to it. for now only 1st interceptor is being worked.

Please help me find where I made a bug.

Here is an example jsfiddle.net/8gm5ap9n/3/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your demo is injecting module dependencies backwards.

Your `ng-app` is `"myApp"` but you are injecting what should be the main module `"myApp"` into the sub module.

When you reverse it and inject sub-module into `"myApp"` module it works as expected.

Use:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.submodule']);
var app2 = angular.module('myApp.submodule',[]);
```

Instead of:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var app2 = angular.module('myApp.submodule', ['myApp']);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8gm5ap9n/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi @charlietfl!

Thanks for your reply. Yes, code your write works as intended, however my real env is a bit complex and my example does not fully reflect it. I will try later to come up with updated example (busy right now with other stuff, sorry). 
Thanks

Comment: Then please be more careful creating examples that are representative of your situation so as not to waste people's time chasing issues that don't exist